# Method to secure the form post Express JS

Tags: html, node.js, http, https, express

I am using a static page loginform.html in the public folder and in this form when the user press submit the username and the password are sent to the server route /login and in this route the authentication is done.

At Server Side:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


app.use(express.compress());

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


var a = ['/'];
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log('First page called');
  res.redirect('loginform.html');
  res.end();
});

app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  console.log('login called');
  //authentication Check//
  res.end();
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

At CLient side :

```
<html>

<style media="screen" type="text/css">
@import url("css/loginform_styles.css");
 </style>

    <head>
        <title>
            Welcome to Label
        </title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="annotationTools/js/md5.js" ></script>
            <script>

                function validateForm()
                {
                    var usrnamefield=document.forms["loginform"]["usrfield"].value;
                    var passwrdfield=document.forms["loginform"]["passfield"].value;

                    if ((usrnamefield==null || usrnamefield=="")||(passwrdfield==null || passwrdfield==""))
                      {
                        document.getElementById('valueerrorlayer').innerHTML ='Username or password field is empty';
                        //document.forms["loginform"]["errorshow"].innerHtml = 'username or password empty';
                      return false;
                      }
                    else return true;
                }
            </script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <div id = "imge_disp">
        <img src="images/logo.jpg"/>

    </div>

    <form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="login" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
        <div id = "content" align = "center">

            <p align="center"><font size="7">LabelDev</font></p> 
            <br />
            <br />

            <label> Please Enter the <b><i>Username</i></b></label>
            <br />
            <br />

            <input type="text"  name = "usrfield" id = "usrfield" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('btnSearch').click()"/>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />

            <label> Please Enter the <b><i>Password</i></b></label>
            <br />
            <br />
            <input type="password"  name = "passfield" id = "passfield" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('btnSearch').click()"/>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />

            <i><p id='valueerrorlayer' style="color:red;"> </p></i>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </div>
    </form>     
    </body>





</html>
```

Problem: I want the username and password to send on the post such that the middleman cannot read them (hashed or encrypted)
Question1 : For this solution using enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is sufficient or not?
Question2 : Is is better to remain in http and do authentication. if yes can you guide me.
Question3 : or move to https and then how to create ssl certificate.

Comment: As you see the word 'urlencoded' means `encoded` data (NOT an `encypted` data). So I recommend to use `SSL`. Search `cheap ssl certificate` for more details :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research I used `HTTPS` certificate and keys to secure the traffic.